# How do I prevent a string from appearing in a result string when a set of child strings are concatenated to form the result string?

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, filter

I have 5 strings, let's call them

- `EarthString`
- `FireString`
- `WindString`
- `WaterString`
- `HeartString`

All of them can have varying length, any of them can be empty, or can be very long (but never null).

These 5 strings are very good friends, and every weekend they are concatenated to form a result string using this c# statement

`ResultString = EarthString + FireString + WindString + WaterString + HeartString`

Depending on the values of these strings, sometimes (only sometimes), `ResultString` will contain "Captain Planet" as a substring.

My question is, how do I manipulate each of the 5 strings before they are concatenated, so that when they are combined, "Captain Planet" will **never** appear as a substring in the resultant string?

The only way I can think of right now is to examine each character in each string, in sequential order, but that seems very tedious. Since each of the 5 good friends strings can be of any length, examining the characters individually will also require some kind of concatenation before we can determine whether any character need to be dropped.

Edit: The resultant string is a filtered version of the 5 strings concatenated together, all the other content remain the same except the "Captain Planet" string is dropped. Yes, i'm looking for a solution which allows the 5 strings to be manipulated before concatenation. (this is actually a simplification of a bigger programming problem i'm encountering). Thanks guys.

Comment: i mean, the way u'll do it, anyway is good, just wanna know how other programmers approach this problem

Comment: It seems like a very weird problem to have. Can these strings be concatenated in any order? Do you have to preprocess all of these strings independently? Do you know the "Captain Planet" substrings at compile-time? Is there one or more than one "Captain Planet" string to look out for? Do you have to conserve the string content after concatenation? Is a series of `string` the most appropriate way to model your problem?

Comment: Is there any real reason you can't remove "Captain Planet" after concatenation?

Comment: Why not a simple string Replace `ResultString.Replace("Captain Planet", "");`

Comment: "*how other programmers approach this problem*" - well. This specific problem? What Habib's (now deleted) answer was. If you're looking for another answer, you need to explain it a bit better. We're often quite pragmatic in our approach to solving problems. =)

Comment: To be honest - even with your further explanation, you're still stuck on doing pre-concatenation to test if "Captain Planet" shows up anywhere.

Comment: ok, the problem i'm having is manipulating the 5 strings before they are concatenated. juz a brief explanation of why i'm doing this: the 5 strings are each part of a datastructure, which may (or may not) be combined with the other 4 datastructures (combined meaning interpreted as huge concatenated string(simplication here)), if i wanna change the output, i gotta change the datastructure. i hope that sorta explains why i'm asking this question.

Comment: Please open another question to ask about the problem without the simplification. Your reduced problem seems too localized and weird, with some of the constraints very ill-defined. (E.g. is it acceptable to drop all content in order to prevent `"Captain Planet"` from appearing?)

Comment: i'm not sure why habib's answer was deleted, i think it's a good suggestion, but i'm looking for a pre concatenation solution. once again, thanks for reading

Comment: yes it's weird, but i've stated very clearly the problem..... manipulating source strings so that a particular string does not appear when concatenated. the content remains the same, juz that the particular string gets dropped.

Comment: At the moment, you have an XY problem. You're trying to solve X by doing Y, so you ask how to accomplish Y. Instead, describe X in more detail - what your input is, what your expected output is. I'm assuming there are some delimiters in your datastructures that need to be removed. In this case, making it more simple is preventing you from getting proper help.

Comment: @Jean, i think i've stated the problem clearly enough. thanks for reading

Comment: @Steen, thanks, the inputs are the 5 strings, the expected output are still the 5 strings, with characters dropped so that a particular string never appears. example: the 5 strings are "I" " Am" " C" "aptain Planet Y" "ea!" the result is, "I" " Am" " " " Y" "ea!"

Comment: If the input strings are "I" "Am" " C" "aptain Pollution H" "ar", what should the result be?

Comment: Per your current description and requirements, and if you specifically don't want to do string.Replace *after* concatenation, jsobo has probably given you the most suitable answer.

Comment: @Jean, in this case non of the characters will be dropped. Because the whole string "Captain Planet" needs to exist (literally) in the concatenated string to qualify it as a set of filtered characters. thanks for reading and for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it pre-concat you could

Assign the start and end of each string a numeric value based on the portion of "CaptainPlanet" they contein.  Ex: if Air = "net the big captain" then it would get 3 for a start value and 7 for an end value.  to determine if you could concat 2 values safely you would just check to see if the end of the left string + start of the right string were not equal to the total length of "CaptainPlanet".  If you had very large strings this would allow you to inspect just the first x and last x characters of the string to compute the start/end value.

This solution doesn't account for short strings like ei air = "Cap" , earth ="tain" and fire="Planet".  In that case you would need to have a special case for tokens that are shorter than the length of "CaptainPlanet"  For those.

Comment: Attempted to make it less a stream of my thoughts and more an answer in some clearer fashion.  Thanks J. Steen

Comment: yes this is the difficulty i'm facing, because the "Captain Planet" string may exist as a concatenation of multiple strings, each of which may have varying length or may even be empty, it's hard to tell where it starts and where it ends. thank you very much for ur answer

Comment: For the last case, you can check if the strings are substrings of the string to avoid. In your example the `earth` string is a substring, you could store some information to complement your test.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you can't just do this?

```
ResultString.Replace("CaptainPlanet", "x");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter how many chars will be dropped, you can remove f.e. all `'C'` in all strings.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer cleared all of the strings, but as pointed out by J.Steen, there was already a formulation of the expected output. So there we go.

1. Run `elementString.Replace("Captain Planet", "")` on every substring.
2. Now you have to identify all the prefixes / suffixes of "Captain Planet" on each of the substrings, and keep that information so that it can be processed before contatenation. That is, e.g. if the substring ends with "Capt", then you should have an information that "substring contains at the end a prefix of the 4 first letters of 'Captain Planet'". You also have to consider the cases of complete substrings (e.g. one of the strings is "ptain Pla"). The problem also becomes more complex if any of the e.g. prefixes can be recursive or repeated (e.g. "CaptainCap" contains 2 kinds of valid prefixes for "CaptainCaptain", and "apt" can be found at two locations in the resulting string);
3. You process that information before concatenation so that the result string has the same thing as `ResultString.Replace("Captain Planet", "")`. Congratulations, you have made your program much more complex than necessary!

But in short, you *cannot* get both the result that you want (all of the substrings intact except for the combined result output) and do the processing wholly before the concatenation step.

Comment: i think it's still a good answer, the problem is this (Steen was right), i'm looking for a particular delimiter in a set of strings. let's say "Captain Planet" is a special string used to begin some special code string in a set of strings, how do i know when it starts? and how do i remove this special delimiter and its code from the string? the code itself is also fragmented across multiple strings. the reason for the fragmentation is because the strings are sent over the network by some application (of which i have no control) and i'm on the receiving end.

Comment: i can't work on the concatenated string because i have no control over the application doing the concatenation. let's juz say i'm the middle man here doing the filtering. i can't drop any string, but i can remove characters in each string. i can add to any string, i can make it empty, or make it very long. these are the transformations i can do. thanks